# How to add a C# constructor using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, constructor, code-generation, roslyn

I am trying to add a constructor to a class using Roslyn. My skeleton code looks like this:

```cs
public class AddConstructor : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        // add constructor?

        return base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
    }
}
```

I was expecting that the `ClassDeclarationSyntax` would have some property like `Constructors` with a method like `Add` but obviously it doesn't. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzhgHwAEBmAAiICYyBhAWACgBvRsti8mgCgEpX2WDdsLL82AX0bigA===

Comment: Roslyn syntax trees are immutable. You can't just add to a node. Instead you have to create a new node consisting of all the original node's children and the nodes you want to add. See: https://joshvarty.com/2014/08/15/learn-roslyn-now-part-5-csharpsyntaxrewriter/

Comment: Thanks but the links provided don't help me. This one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70598406/how-to-create-a-constructor-with-a-parameter-with-roslyn) shows me how to create a new constructor but it doesn't include any code for adding it to an existing class. Is VisitClassDeclaration the correct method to override to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't the constructor just a member like any other, which you add with `WithMembers`? `ConstructorDeclarationSyntax` derives from `MemberDeclarationSyntax`

Comment: Ah! That sounds very promising. I will give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @canton7, using WithMembers was the answer.